# phpunit tries to include directories when given empty suffix

Tags: php, phpunit, warnings, composer-php

I'm trying to run tests on my new project. The directory layout is as follows:

```
src/ (project's code here)    
test/
    EviType/
        Main.php
    phpunit.xml
composer.json
```

Phpunit is installed with composer (the so-called per-project dependency):

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": ">=3.7.5"
    },
}
```

And I run `composer install/update` with `--dev` option.

Phpunit configuration is defined with a minimalistic `test/phpunit.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<phpunit colors="true">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite>
            <directory suffix="">EviType</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

And the test code in `test/EviType/Main.php` is also as short as it could be:

```
<?php
class Main extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function test()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

So when I run phpunit:

```
php54 -C vendor/bin/phpunit -c test/
```

(The system has a number of php versions installed, php54 is my alias for `/usr/local/php54/bin/php`.)

I get a couple of neat warning messages:

```
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.5
Content-type: text/html

<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  include_once(/path/to/docs/test): failed to open stream: Success in <b>/path/to/docs/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Util/Fileloader.php</b> on line <b>92</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  include_once(): Failed opening '/path/to/docs/test' for inclusion (include_path='/path/to/docs/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/:/path/to/docs/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/../../symfony/yaml:/path/to/docs/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/vendor/phpunit/php-text-template/:/path/to/docs/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream/:/path/to/docs/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/vendor/phpunit/php-file-iterator/:/path/to/docs/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/:/path/to/docs/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/vendor/phpunit/php-timer/:/path/to/docs/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/:.:/usr/local/php54/lib/php') in <b>/path/to/docs/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Util/Fileloader.php</b> on line <b>92</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  include_once(/path/to/docs/test/EviType): failed to open stream: Success in <b>/path/to/docs/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Util/Fileloader.php</b> on line <b>92</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  include_once(): Failed opening '/path/to/docs/test/EviType' for inclusion (include_path='/path/to/docs/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/:/path/to/docs/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/../../symfony/yaml:/path/to/docs/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/vendor/phpunit/php-text-template/:/path/to/docs/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream/:/path/to/docs/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/vendor/phpunit/php-file-iterator/:/path/to/docs/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/:/path/to/docs/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/vendor/phpunit/php-timer/:/path/to/docs/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/:.:/usr/local/php54/lib/php') in <b>/path/to/docs/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Util/Fileloader.php</b> on line <b>92</b><br />
PHPUnit 3.7.14 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from /path/to/docs/test/phpunit.xml

.

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 2.50Mb

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

The assertion report makes me happy, but I can't see why it even tries to include directories:

```
include_once(/path/to/docs/test)
```

as well as what the enigmatic `failed to open stream: Success` clause means. It seemed to be a [php bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45130), but it should be fixed like ages ago.

Setting something like:

```
<php>
    <ini name="display_errors" value="0"/>
</php>
```

makes those warnings disappear, but I feel like there's a more deep problem in phpunit installation to be dug out.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should set the suffix to ".php" - otherwise phpunit tries to include all files that have "" in them, which are all files and all directories.

Comment: Oh I see now, I really should. Thank you for figuring that out! 

I believe it is an issue with PHPUnit. Whatever suffix is given, including directories is not a right thing to do.